# Ignored call to Java method from C++

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I am trying to repeatedly call a Java method from C++ inside an event handler that is executed several times along the lifetime of my program.

To do that I have the following code.

1. A JNI helper class to get a valid instance to JNIEnv and clean it up appropriately.

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <jni.h>

static bool getJniEnv(JavaVM *vm, JNIEnv **env) {
    bool didAttachThread = false;
    *env = nullptr;
    auto get_env_result = vm->GetEnv((void**)env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
    if (get_env_result == JNI_EDETACHED) {
        if (vm->AttachCurrentThread(env, NULL) == JNI_OK) {
            didAttachThread = true;
        } else {
            throw;
        }
    } else if (get_env_result == JNI_EVERSION) {
        // Unsupported JNI version.
        throw;
    }
    return didAttachThread;
}

class ScopedEnv {
public:
    ScopedEnv(JavaVM *vm) : vm(vm), attachedToVm(false) {
        attachedToVm = getJniEnv(vm, &env);
    }

    ScopedEnv(const ScopedEnv&) = delete;
    ScopedEnv& operator=(const ScopedEnv&) = delete;

    virtual ~ScopedEnv() {
        if (attachedToVm) {
            vm->DetachCurrentThread();
            attachedToVm = false;
        }
    }

    JNIEnv *getEnv() const { return env; }

private:
    bool attachedToVm;
    JavaVM *vm;
    JNIEnv *env;
};
```

2. A C++ wrapper to store global references to the Java object implementing the method that I want to call:

```cpp
class PageEventObserver {
    JavaVM *vm;
    jclass pageClass;
    jobject pageObj;

public:
    PageEventObserver(JavaVM *vm, jclass klass, jobject obj) : vm(vm), pageClass(klass), pageObj(obj) {}
    ~PageEventObserver();

    void onLoadChanged(WebKitLoadEvent);
    [...]
};
```

With its corresponding implementation:

```cpp
[...]
void PageEventObserver::onLoadChanged(WebKitLoadEvent loadEvent) {
    ALOGV("PageEventObserver::onLoadChanged tid %d", gettid());
    try {
        JNIEnv *env = ScopedEnv(vm).getEnv();
        jmethodID onLoadChanged = env->GetMethodID(pageClass, "onLoadChanged", "(I)V");
        if (onLoadChanged == nullptr) {
            throw;
        }
        ALOGV("Calling method env %p pageClass %p pageObj %p", env, pageClass, pageObj);
        env->CallVoidMethod(pageObj, onLoadChanged, (int)loadEvent);
        ALOGV("Called");
    } catch(int) {
        ALOGE("Could not send onLoadChanged event");
    }
}
```

3. The creation of the `PageEventObserver` wrapper happens on an initial call from the JNI layer to the following method:

```java
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_wpe_wpe_BrowserGlue_newWebView(JNIEnv* env, jobject, jobject pageObj, jint width, jint height)
{
    ALOGV("BrowserGlue.newWebView tid %d", gettid());
    jclass pageClass = env->GetObjectClass(pageObj);
    jclass _pageClass = reinterpret_cast<jclass>(env->NewGlobalRef(pageClass));
    jobject _pageObj = reinterpret_cast<jobject>(env->NewGlobalRef(pageObj));
    JavaVM *vm;
    env->GetJavaVM(&vm);

    std::unique_ptr<PageEventObserver> observer = std::make_unique<PageEventObserver>(vm, _pageClass, _pageObj);

    wpe_browser_glue_new_web_view(width, height, std::move(observer), [env, pageObj, pageClass] (long viewRef) {
        jmethodID onReady = env->GetMethodID(pageClass, "onWebViewReady", "(J)V");
        if (onReady == nullptr) {
            return;
        }
        ALOGV("webview %ld", (jlong)viewRef);
        env->CallVoidMethod(pageObj, onReady, (jlong)viewRef);
    });
}
```

There I create the global references to `pageClass` and `pageObj` (I suspect I can skip creating a global reference to `pageClass`, but that is out of the scope of the question) and create the `PageEventObserver` instance passing the global references to its constructor. The `PageEventObserver` instance is then passed to `wpe_browser_glue_new_web_view` which ends up saving it as a static.

4. At some point, an event handler is executed:

```cpp
static void onLoadChanged(WebKitWebView*, WebKitLoadEvent loadEvent, gpointer) {
    ALOGV("onLoadCHanged %d", loadEvent);
    pageObserver->onLoadChanged(loadEvent);
}
```

Within this event handler, I make use of the static `PageEventObserver` instance, calling its `onLoadChanged` method.

The **first** time this event handler is executed, everything works properly. I see this in the logs:

```
 03-26 10:15:41.754  V  [31342/31401] WPE Glue onLoadCHanged 0
 03-26 10:15:41.754  V  [31342/31401] WPE Glue PageEventObserver::onLoadChanged tid 31401
 03-26 10:15:41.754  V  [31342/31401] WPE Glue Calling method env 0xb400007915a86030 pageClass 0x294a pageObj 0x2956
 03-26 10:15:41.754  V  [31342/31401] WPE page0 onLoadChanged ...com.wpe.wpeview.WPEView{d68f3ce V.E...... ........ 0,154-1080,2151 #7f08019e app:id/wpe_view}
 03-26 10:15:41.754  V  [31342/31401] WPEView  Load changed /////  <-- This is inside the Java method I want to call
 03-26 10:15:41.754  V  [31342/31401] WPE Glue Called
```

However, on subsequent executions of the same event handler, the Java method is **not** called, but I see no error or crash at all:

```
 03-26 10:15:45.807  V  [31342/31401] WPE Glue onLoadCHanged 3
 03-26 10:15:45.808  V  [31342/31401] WPE Glue PageEventObserver::onLoadChanged tid 31401
 03-26 10:15:45.808  V  [31342/31401] WPE Glue Calling method env 0xb400007915a86030 pageClass 0x294a pageObj 0x2956
 03-26 10:15:45.808  V  [31342/31401] WPE Glue Called
```

Note the missing logs between `WPE Glue Calling ...` and `WPE Glue called`.

Comment: I am using them within the `PageEventObserver::onLoadChanged` implementation. There `pageObj` and `pageClass` are the global refs stored in the `PageEventObserver` instance.

Comment: Yes, and they are given to the `PageEventObserver` constructor: `std::unique_ptr<PageEventObserver> observer = std::make_unique<PageEventObserver>(vm, _pageClass, _pageObj);`. They are then used in the `PageEventObserver::onLoadChanged` method as mentioned before.

Comment: oh I see.......

Comment: I don't see the code that's supposed to print those missing logs. For all we know, you might not be executing those log statement sometimes (e.g. returning or throwing an exception before reaching them).

Comment: As far as _"I suspect I can skip creating a global reference to `pageClass`"_ is concerned: you can't share a local reference across threads. So if you save a reference for use on some other thread, it needs to be a global reference.

Comment: Thank you @Michael! You gave me the perfect pointer. The problem was on an associated event handler that was throwing an uncatched exception: `android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit. There was an uncatched exception being thrown from an associated event handler:

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Fixing that makes everything work as expected. I see the missing logs now.